# How do I hypenate correctly without creating gaps in paragraphs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get hyphenation working correctly.

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- lset language-->
<html lang="nl">
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chivo:400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<title>HYPHENATE</title>
<style>
html {
    background: #fff;
    /* Warning: Needed for oldIE support, but words are broken up letter-by-letter */
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-all;

    /* Non standard for webkit */
    word-break: break-word;

    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}

.product-name {
    width: 113px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #231f20;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Chivo", sans-serif;
    background-color: grey;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="product-name">Bijzettafel Aspen met tijdschriftenrek</div>
</body>

</html>
```

This results in a text box with is hyphenated as follows:

[image: hyphenated etxts]

I can forgive instances where words are hyphenated incorrectly as I understand that some words aren't always in 'htmls' dictionary. But what I find strange is that hyphenated words somethimes leave gaps in paragraphs. In this example this would make much more sense:

```
BIJZETTA-
FEL ASPEN
MET TIJD-
SCHRIFTEN-
REK
```

As after hyphenation there would be enough space after 'MET' TO PUT 'TIJD-' BEHIND IT.

How can I fix the code so that hyphenated syllables automatically continue behind previous words when there would be plenty of space for it?

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that the browser has a hyphenation algorithm and you can't interfere with it. The browser will lay the text out as it wants. (The same is true in MS Word, InDesign or any other text software, of course. It's just that with proper layout software, you get more control over the text properties.)

The reason that the browser has moved "TIJD-" to the next line is that it's fractionally too wide for the space the browser has left to place text in so it has no choice but to move it.

You have two options for changing how the text flows. The first is to make a tiny adjustment to the element width, the font size or the font kerning. (You can do this across the whole text, or just to offending portions using a `span`.) This will change the maths behind the text flow and may let you produce a more aesthetic result.

The second is to use hard spaces (&nbsp;), thin spaces (&#x2009;) or (as a real bodge) `span`s with padding and no real spaces at all, to try and force the browser to lay the text out as you want.

But, because all browsers are different, you can't guarantee the result, whatever option you choose. If it's essential to get the right look, you'll need to use an image (but don't forget the accessibility if you do)!

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough I found out that by commenting out 'overflow: hidden' and adding 'display: table' to the product-name class I got what I wanted. Removing 'overflow: hidden' made the syllables move nicely behind the previous words. When I went to another browser window those syllables moved down again for some reason, but that was fixed by adding 'display: table'. The resulting code below. Leading to above good result. Not a clue why this works but css sometimes works mysteriously :-)

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- lset language-->
<html lang="nl">
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chivo:400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<title>HYPHENATE</title>
<style>
html {
background: #fff;
/* Warning: Needed for oldIE support, but words are broken up letter-by-letter */
-ms-word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-all;

/* Non standard for webkit */
word-break: break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
}

.product-name {
   /* added display: table*/
    display: table;
    width: 113px;
    height: 300px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #231f20;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Chivo", sans-serif;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    background-color: grey;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="product-name">Bijzettafel Aspen met tijdschriftenrek</div>
</body>

</html>
```